# mysql stored function: how to select multiple results and process them

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

mysql stored function: how to select multiple results and process them. For example,

```
create function hello() return decimal(10,2) determistic begin

   select value1, value2 from Foo;
   // process multiple rows in result set here
   for (....) {

   }

 end
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html says:

> *Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored procedure but not within a stored function.*

You can't run `select ... from Foo` in a stored function as you would in a stored procedure, because that `select` will generate a result set with multiple columns and multiple values.

A stored function can only return a single scalar value. In your example, you are returning a `decimal(10,2)`. So whatever you do with your queries, the result must end up in an expression in a [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/return.html).

If you need to run a `select` query, you can store the result into a variable and then return that variable.

```
...
begin
  declare d decimal(10,2);
  select <expr> into d from Foo limit 1;
  return d;
end
```

Or you can run a cursor (as suggested by the link posted by @stickybit above in a comment), and process the result of the query row-by-row. See an example in that documentation page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

I can't go into more detail, because you have not described what you're trying to do with your function, and the example you show does not make it clear.